# Listbox is showing class name instead of values

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a project where the user is able to create different animals. 
This is how the inheritance work:

> Animal class is the parent for all classes.
>
> Mammal class inherit from Animal class.
>
> Dog class inherit from Mammal class.
>
> Cat class inherit from Mammal class
>
> Reptile class inherit from Animal class
>
> Snake class inherit from Reptile class
>
> Lizard class inherit from Reptile class

The user is able to choose what animal to create. There is one listbox showing the type of animal (`Mammal` and `Reptile`) and there is a listbox next to it that that depending on the type of animal selected by the user, it displays its animals.

For exampel, if the user selects `Mammal` in the listbox, the listbox next to it displays `Dog` and `Cat`.

The user is then able to select the animal to create and then input some information about that animal and create it to make it show on a result listbox.

I also want it to show a food schedule when an animal is selected on the result listbox. 
For example if a user selects a dog(after creating it) on the result listbox, the dog's food schedule is to be displayed on a schedule listbox.

**The problem** is that when I try to select an item on that listbox, the only thing adding to the schedule listbox is class name `FoodSchedule`

> Assign.FoodSchedule

Here are my classes:

There is a `FoodSchedule` class that works as a class manager.

```
public class FoodSchedule
    {
       private List<string> foodDescriptionList;

       public FoodSchedule()
       {
           foodDescriptionList = new List<string>();
       }
        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                if ((foodDescriptionList != null))
                {
                    return foodDescriptionList.Count;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }

        public void AddScheduleItem(string item)
        {

            foodDescriptionList.Add(item);
        }


        public string GetFoodSchedule(int index)
        {
           if(ValidateIndex(index))
           {
                return foodDescriptionList[index];
           }
           else
           {
               return null;
           }
        }

        public bool ValidateIndex(int index)
        {
            return ((index >= 0) && (index < foodDescriptionList.Count));
        }

    }
}
```

The instance variable `foodDescriptionList` is a collection of string elements where each element is a line of text that describes a part of the feeding schedule.

The info about the schedule is to be contained and filled in an instance of `FoodSchedule` in for example the `Dog` class (hard-coded, through an overridden method)

```
class Dog : Mammal
    {
        private FoodSchedule foodScedule = new FoodSchedule();


public override FoodSchedule FoodDescription
        {
            get
            {
                return this.foodScedule;
            }
        }
public override string GetSpecies()
        {
            return "Dog";
        }

     public override FoodSchedule GetFoodSchedule()
        {

            foodScedule.AddScheduleItem("Some text");


            return foodScedule;
        }
```

My `mainForm`:

```
 public partial class MainForm : Form
    {  
        private FoodSchedule m_foodManager = new FoodSchedule();
        private Dog m_dog = new Dog();
  FoodSchedule animal = m_dog.GetFoodSchedule();

                   if (animal != null)
             {
                    //Adds to the list.
                 foodlst.Items.Add(animal.ToString()); //foodlst is the schedule listbox  
              }    
                foodlst.DisplayMember = "FoodDescription";
```

Comment: It's because you are calling add animal.ToString(); If you don't overload ToString on a class it just returns the name of the class. You need to do something like foodlst.Items.Add(animal.GetSpecies());

Comment: You need to add an ToString method to each of your classes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, I gather that you want to display the food description (list of string) for the selected animal i.e. Dog

To achieve this in your FoodSchedule class add a property

```
public List<string> FoodDescriptionList 
{
     get
     {
          return foodDescriptionList;
      }
 }
```

And in your main form you can bind this collection to your listbox

```
if (animal != null)
{
    //Adds to the list.
    foodlst.DataSource = animal.FoodDescriptionList;
}
```